# Integral of product of Legendre polynomial and exponential function

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

Kindly help me with the following integral :

$ 
I_l(a) = \int_{-1}^{+1} dx\, e^{a x} P_l(x)  \quad  
$
($a$ is real and positive).

I thought to use the following relation given in Gradshteiyn and also in Prudnikov,

$\int_{-1}^{+1}\, dx\,  e^{ipx} P_l(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{p}} \, e^{\frac{i l \pi}{2}} J_{l + \frac{1}{2}} (p) $.

But it seems that the formula cited there holds for real $p$. Can someone please enlighten me if $p$ becomes complex? I am unable to trace the original source.

Comment: If you know the equality holds over $\mathbb{R}^+$, you can prove that it holds over $\mathbb{C}$ by (1) noting the RHS is analytic over $\mathbb{C}$ ignoring the removable singularity at $p=0$, (2) showing the LHS is analytic over $\mathbb{C}$ by using Morera's theorem, (3) appealing to the identity theorem.